# WooCommerce restrict coupon to user role error message

Tags: woocommerce

I'm using WooCommerce to restrict a coupon to the user role "gold-member" which works fine but I'm trying to change the message displayed when an invalid user tries to use the coupon:

```
Sorry, coupon code "goldmember10" is not valid with your customer role.
```

My code

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_error','coupon_error_message_change',10,3 );
function coupon_error_message_change($err, $err_code, $parm ) {
    switch ( $err_code ) {
        case 100:
            $err = sprintf( __( 'Sorry, coupon code "%s" is not valid.', 'woocommerce' ), $parm->get_code() );
            break;
    }
    return $err;
}
```

$err_code matches 100 per [class-wc-coupon.php](https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-class-wc-coupon.html) but the message does not get updated.

Answer (score 1):

This should suffice:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_coupon_error( $err, $err_code, $coupon ) {
    // Compare
    if ( intval( $err_code ) === WC_COUPON::E_WC_COUPON_INVALID_FILTERED ) {
        // Message
        $err = sprintf( __( 'Sorry, coupon code "%s" is not valid.', 'woocommerce' ), $coupon->get_code() );
    } else {
        $err = 'DEBUG INFORMATION, error code number = ' . intval( $err_code );
    }
    
    return $err;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_error', 'filter_woocommerce_coupon_error', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but this doesn't change the message.

Comment: @Junky I tested it 2x in the latest version of WordPress and WooCommerce, 
Have you already debugged your code to see if it is actually error code number 100 and not another number? see my updated answer

Comment: When I echo $err_code, 100 is displayed above the coupon error message. The Debug line does not display anything.

Comment: @Junky 
Then something else is wrong with your setup. I can't add more than a tested and working answer

Comment: Thanks for your input. If I find that something in my code is preventing your answer from working, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Junky the only thing I can think of is that you/or a plugin you are using already uses the same hook and overwrites it. Try to adjust the priority: change `add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_error', 'filter_woocommerce_coupon_error', 10, 3 );` to  `add_filter( 'woocommerce_coupon_error', 'filter_woocommerce_coupon_error', 1, 3 );`